# is request id asn.1 encoded?

Tags: snmp, wireshark, asn.1

I posted this to the net-snmp mailing list Monday and got no reply, so I am trying here. 
I am confused and I hope someone can help.

I am writing an SNMP agent for a Cortex M4 application.
The SNMP books I have bought and what I have read on the net indicate that all data fields should be ASN.1 encoded. I know the OIDs are ASN.1 encoded. I am not sure if that applies to other fields like Request ID.

Looking at snmp commands sent by net-snmp, it appears that the Request ID field is a simple (4 byte) 32 bit integer.
Here is a screen shot showing an snmpget transaction monitored through Wireshark:

http://www.ko4bb.com/net-snmp/RequestID.png

It shows the RequestID to be 1750020546 (decimal) and 0x684F31C2 in hex. The data field in Wireshark also shows it to be “68 4f 31 c2”

This is not ASN.1 encoded, otherwise the first 3 bytes would have their bit 7 set to 1 and the last byte would have bit 7 set to 0, meaning the  first 3 values would be >0x7F and the last value should be < 0x80

So is ASN.1 not used for the RequestID field?

Answer (score 2):

I added the wireshark tag, as this is purely a Wireshark issue.

The Request ID field, is strictly in ASN.1 BER format, which is `02 04 68 4f 31 c2`.

You should be careful that Wireshark is too smart to parse the data and hide some details from you.

Please check the botton panel where `68 4f 31 c2` is highlighted. Wireshark highlights them, but intentionally ignore `02 04` ahead. That's the problem.

As @GuyHarris pointed out in the comment, this Wireshark behavior is configurable. Other packet analyzers (such as Microsoft Network Monitor) might behave differently in the same scenario.

Comment: "The Request ID field, is strictly in ASN.1 format, which is `02 04 68 4f 31 c2`."  That's ASN.1 Basic Encoding Rules (BER) format; ASN.1 doesn't specify an encoding (there's also the Packed Encoding rules).  "You should be careful that Wireshark is too smart to parse the data and hide some details from you."  If you enable Wireshark's "Show internal BER encapsulation tokens" preference for the BER protocol, it will show you those details; that just doesn't happen to be the default.

Comment: Thank you, but this is not quite my issue. 02 04 68 4f 31 c2 does not appear to be ASN.1 BER encoded. The definition for ASN.1 BER says that if the value is > 127, the first byte contains data on the 7 LSBs and bit 7 is set to 1, then the remainder is coded on the next byte. For instance, the value 42564 should be encoded as 0x82, 0xCC, 0x44, or if you include the headers, 0x02, 0x03, 0x82, 0xcc, 0x44. It seems that net-snmp simply encodes the integer value as 4 bytes, regardless of the value. I have not found a way to force net-snmp to issue a Request ID value of 1 or 2 for instance.

Comment: This is the way integers are encoded in the OID field for instance. It appears that this encoding rule only applies to the OID and probably this is my mistake.

Comment: On further note, it seems like I have confused BER (the way data fields such as Request ID are encoded ) and PER (used for OID field).

Comment: Guy, thank you for the tip on turning on  Wireshark's "Show internal BER encapsulation tokens". Wireshark is a beast :)